# STL: overloading and getter method

Tags: c++, stl

The object described by this header file needs to be placed in a priority_queue; therefore I do operator overloading at the bottom of the below code. When I try to call one of the getter functions on a member of process that is in a priority queue, I get an error of this format:

test.cpp:xx: error: passing ... as ... argument of ... discards qualifiers

As you can see I tried a cheap workaround by declaring certain variables as public, but when I tried to change these from the main program, it says it cannot change the variables from a read-only file. I'm pretty new to STL.  What are some ways of solving this, or ways around it?

```
class process
{
    int priority; //for priority queues

public:
    process();
    ~process(){};

    void setPri(int newPri) {priority = newPri;}
    int getPri() {return priority;}
};

class compareProcess
{
public:
    bool operator() (process& param1, process& param2)
    {
        if (param1.getPri() > param2.getPri()) return true;
        else return false;
    } 
};
```

Comment: Please describe more precisely the error message. Put the error message complete and point us to the line number that fails to compile.

Comment: `discards qualifier` is most likely a constness problem

Comment: Anyway, why you no indent?

Comment: Can you show us example usage and the line that compiler reports as problematic?

Comment: And why do you say it's STL related? There aren't any templates used.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to write

```
bool operator() ( const process& param1, const process& param2) const { ... }
```

That means the parameters need to be `const` as required for http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting suggests that you are passing a const object as a parameter that is a reference to a non-const object.  The likely issue is this line:

```
bool operator() (process& param1, process& param2)
```

Since this method does not alter the passed objects in any way, they should be declared const:

```
bool operator() (process const & param1, process const & param2)
```

This can happen if you try to pass a `process const` object, or if you try to pass a `process` temporary, which cannot bind to a non-const reference.

You will have to alter the definition of `process` so that any methods that do not change the object are declared `const` as well, otherwise you won't be able to do very much with these const references.  (In this case, since `getPri()` is not declared as a const method, you will not be able to call it.)

Answer (score 0):

Make `getPri()` a const function:

`int getPri() const {return priority;}`

Now in the overloaded `operator()`:

```
 bool operator() (const process& param1, const process& param2) const
 {
    return param1.getPri() > param2.getPri();
 }
```

Edit:  You should make all of your "getter" functions `const` that do not change the state of the object.

Comment: For that matter, make _all_ getter methods `const`. If they don't change anything, tell the compiler so.